# kubernetes on microk8s yaml file not working

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Yesterday, I installed kubernetes microk8s on my private laptop to learn about kubernetes,
But even on first simple file with PersistentVolume I'm getting a lot of validation errors,

I have installed microk8s on Ubuntu from below source:
https://microk8s.io/?_ga=2.70856272.1723042697.1642604373-620897147.1642604373v

The issue is when firstly I wanted to create pv:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: redis-pv
spec:
storageClassName: ""
capacity:
storage: 1Gi
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
hostPath:
path: "/mnt/data"
```

and I'm gettting below errors:

```
kubectl apply -f pv-data.yml -n testing

error: error validating "pv-data.yml": error validating data: [ValidationError(PersistentVolume): unknown field "accessModes" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolume, ValidationError(PersistentVolume): unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolume, ValidationError(PersistentVolume): unknown field "path" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolume, ValidationError(PersistentVolume): unknown field "storage" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolume, ValidationError(PersistentVolume): unknown field "storageClassName" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolume]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Can someone help me with that ? Maybe I have microk8s not properly installed ? Because this is very simple yaml file.

also I would like to attach status of microk8s:

```
microk8s status

microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    dashboard            # The Kubernetes dashboard
    dns                  # CoreDNS
    ha-cluster           # Configure high availability on the current node
    ingress              # Ingress controller for external access
    metrics-server       # K8s Metrics Server for API access to service metrics
  disabled:
    ambassador           # Ambassador API Gateway and Ingress
    cilium               # SDN, fast with full network policy
    dashboard-ingress    # Ingress definition for Kubernetes dashboard
    fluentd              # Elasticsearch-Fluentd-Kibana logging and monitoring
    gpu                  # Automatic enablement of Nvidia CUDA
    helm                 # Helm 2 - the package manager for Kubernetes
    helm3                # Helm 3 - Kubernetes package manager
    host-access          # Allow Pods connecting to Host services smoothly
    inaccel              # Simplifying FPGA management in Kubernetes
    istio                # Core Istio service mesh services
    jaeger               # Kubernetes Jaeger operator with its simple config
    kata                 # Kata Containers is a secure runtime with lightweight VMS
    keda                 # Kubernetes-based Event Driven Autoscaling
    knative              # The Knative framework on Kubernetes.
    kubeflow             # Kubeflow for easy ML deployments
    linkerd              # Linkerd is a service mesh for Kubernetes and other frameworks
    metallb              # Loadbalancer for your Kubernetes cluster
    multus               # Multus CNI enables attaching multiple network interfaces to pods
    openebs              # OpenEBS is the open-source storage solution for Kubernetes
    openfaas             # OpenFaaS serverless framework
    portainer            # Portainer UI for your Kubernetes cluster
    prometheus           # Prometheus operator for monitoring and logging
    rbac                 # Role-Based Access Control for authorisation
    registry             # Private image registry exposed on localhost:32000
    storage              # Storage class; allocates storage from host directory
    traefik              # traefik Ingress controller for external access
```

Comment: yaml is very strict on indentation, the reason being that it allows other types of content to be embedded and can only use indentation to know where things start and end.

Comment: Be very careful because you can get so many different errors and things not working if you get the indentation wrong! Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Issue related to yaml indentation , you can use valid online examples like

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

or just try fix it on your intuition , most of time you can make it done

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: redis-pv
spec:
 storageClassName: ""
 capacity:
   storage: 1Gi
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 hostPath:
   path: "/mnt/data"
```